# SwiftUI: Maintain state of bottom sheet when another sheet is opened

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a very complex app and I have created a sample app to explain my problem.

My app has a bottom sheet (BottomSheetView) which has navigation destinations to drill into other views within the sheet. There is also a button (info button) within the app which when clicked opens another sheet.

Let's say I tap on a button within BottomSheetView which opens BottomSheetSubView as navigation destination. Then tap on the info button on the app which opens another sheet(InfoView and InfoSubView) over BottomSheetView. When I cancel out of this info sheet view, I notice that bottom sheet's state changes i.e. bottom sheet shows BottomSheetView instead of BottomSheetSubView.

I want to continue showing BottomSheetSubView since that was the view before I opened info view. How can I keep the state of bottom sheet the same?

Sharing my code below. You probably will have to run it to understand the problem.

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation

class MainViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var showBottomPanel = false
    @Published var selectedDetent: PresentationDetent = .fraction(0.25)
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var mainViewModel: MainViewModel = MainViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                Text("This is the main view").padding(.top, 100.0)
                Spacer()
            }
            .onAppear {
                mainViewModel.showBottomPanel = true
            }
            .overlay(alignment: .bottomTrailing) {
                self.infoView
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $mainViewModel.showBottomPanel) {
                ZStack {
                    Color.gray.opacity(0.5)
                    BottomSheetView().padding(.top, 15.0).environmentObject(mainViewModel)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private var infoView: some View {
        InfoView().padding(.bottom, 210.0).padding(.trailing, 10.0)
    }
}

// MARK: View's related to bottom sheet.

struct BottomSheetView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var mainViewModel: MainViewModel
    @State var showSubView = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ZStack {
                Color.gray.opacity(0.5).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                VStack {
                    Button { self.showSubView = true } label: {
                        Text("Click Me")
                    }
                }
                .navigationDestination(isPresented: $showSubView) {
                    BottomSheetSubView()
                }
            }
        }
        .presentationDetents([.fraction(0.25), .large], selection: $mainViewModel.selectedDetent)
        .interactiveDismissDisabled(true)
        .presentationBackgroundInteraction(.enabled)
    }
}

struct BottomSheetSubView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("This is a sub view and should stay active.")
        }
    }
}

// MARK: View's related to info view/info button

struct InfoView: View {
    @State var showInfoSubView = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            Button {
                showInfoSubView = true
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: "info.circle.fill").resizable().foregroundColor(.blue).frame(width: 30, height: 30)
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showInfoSubView) {
            InfoSubView()
        }
    }
}

struct InfoSubView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                Text("This is info sub view... tap on cancel button")
            }
            .presentationDetents([.large])
            .interactiveDismissDisabled(true)
            .presentationBackgroundInteraction(.enabled)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                    Button {
                        presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                    } label: {
                        Text("Cancel").font(.body)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Steps to produce the problem:

- Run the code above.
- Tap on "Click Me" on the bottom panel which will navigate it to subview which says - "This is a sub view and should stay active".
- Now don't do anything with bottom panel, but tap on info button to open info view.
- Once info view is opened, tap 'Cancel' on top left of this panel to close the info sheet.
- Notice the bottom panel goes back to "Click Me" view instead of "This is a sub view and should stay active" view.

I wish to keep "This is a sub view and should stay active" active in the bottom panel once info view is closed. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve the desired behavior is to move the showSubView state management up to the MainViewModel, just like you're managing the showBottomPanel. This way, the state is not tied to the view's lifecycle, and dismissing the info view will not reset the state of the bottom panel.

```
import SwiftUI
    import Foundation
    
    class MainViewModel: ObservableObject {
        @Published var showBottomPanel = false
        @Published var selectedDetent: PresentationDetent = .fraction(0.25)
        @Published var showBottomSheetSubView = false // Manage the bottom sheet's subview presentation state
    }
    
    struct ContentView: View {
        @StateObject var mainViewModel: MainViewModel = MainViewModel()
    
        var body: some View {
            NavigationStack {
                VStack {
                    Text("This is the main view").padding(.top, 100.0)
                    Spacer()
                }
                .onAppear {
                    mainViewModel.showBottomPanel = true
                }
                .overlay(alignment: .bottomTrailing) {
                    self.infoView
                }
                .sheet(isPresented: $mainViewModel.showBottomPanel) {
                    ZStack {
                        Color.gray.opacity(0.5)
                        BottomSheetView().padding(.top, 15.0).environmentObject(mainViewModel)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    
        private var infoView: some View {
            InfoView().padding(.bottom, 210.0).padding(.trailing, 10.0)
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: View's related to bottom sheet.
    
    struct BottomSheetView: View {
        @EnvironmentObject var mainViewModel: MainViewModel
        
        var body: some View {
            NavigationStack {
                ZStack {
                    Color.gray.opacity(0.5).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                    VStack {
                        Button {
                            mainViewModel.showBottomSheetSubView = true // Use the view model's state
                        } label: {
                            Text("Click Me")
                        }
                    }
                    .navigationDestination(isPresented: $mainViewModel.showBottomSheetSubView) { // Use the view model's state
                        BottomSheetSubView()
                    }
                }
            }
            .presentationDetents([.fraction(0.25), .large], selection: $mainViewModel.selectedDetent)
            .interactiveDismissDisabled(true)
            .presentationBackgroundInteraction(.enabled)
        }
    }
    
    struct BottomSheetSubView: View {
        var body: some View {
            VStack {
                Text("This is a sub view and should stay active.")
            }
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: View's related to info view/info button
    
    struct InfoView: View {
        @State var showInfoSubView = false
    
        var body: some View {
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                Button {
                    showInfoSubView = true
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "info.circle.fill").resizable().foregroundColor(.blue).frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                }
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $showInfoSubView) {
                InfoSubView()
            }
        }
    }
    
    struct InfoSubView: View {
        @Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode
    
        var body: some View {
            NavigationStack {
                VStack {
                    Text("This is info sub view... tap on cancel button")
                }
                .presentationDetents([.large])
                .interactiveDismissDisabled(true)
                .presentationBackgroundInteraction(.enabled)
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                        Button {
                            presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                        } label: {
                            Text("Cancel").font(.body)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    // Preview
    struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
```

Comment: This was a good. Thanks for sharing! One other solution that I had tried was opening BottomSubView as a sheet on ContentView instead of Navigation Destination on Sub View. That worked, but my actual app is very complex and has multiple sheet's on Content View, hence was avoiding that.

Comment: I now have one more sheet i.e. one more level deep and the same idea of moving the published property to view model of presenting view doesn't help when I go one more level deep. Any idea why is that happening? I posted a new question for the same here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77998161/swiftui-maintain-state-of-sheet-when-another-sheet-is-opened-on-top-of-it