# Maintain state of sheet when another sheet is opened on top of it

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a very complex app and I have created a sample app to explain my problem.

My app has a sheet(MainSheetView) on main launching view which has navigation destinations to drill into other views within the sheet. There is also a button (info button) within the app which when clicked opens another sheet.

Let's say I tap on a button within MainSheetView which opens SubSheetA as navigation destination. There is another button on SubSheetA which when tapped opens SubSheetB as navigation destination. Then tap on the info button on the app which opens another sheet(InfoView and InfoSubView) over SubSheetB. When I cancel out of this InfoSubView, I notice that sub sheet's state changes i.e. SubSheetB is dismissed and SubSheetA is visible instead.

I want to continue showing SubSheetB since that was the view before I opened info view. How can I prevent SubSheetB from dismissing?

***Sharing my code below. You probably will have to run it to understand the problem.***

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation

class MainViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var showMainSheet = false
    @Published var selectedDetent: PresentationDetent = .fraction(0.25)
    @Published var showSubSheetA = false // Manage the bottom sheet's subview presentation state
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var mainViewModel: MainViewModel = MainViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                Text("This is the main view").padding(.top, 100.0)
                Spacer()
            }
            .onAppear {
                mainViewModel.showMainSheet = true
            }
            .overlay(alignment: .bottomTrailing) {
                self.infoView
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $mainViewModel.showMainSheet) {
                ZStack {
                    Color.gray.opacity(0.5)
                    MainSheetView().padding(.top, 15.0).environmentObject(mainViewModel)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private var infoView: some View {
        InfoView().padding(.bottom, 210.0).padding(.trailing, 10.0)
    }
}

// MARK: View's related to main sheet.

struct MainSheetView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var mainViewModel: MainViewModel
    @StateObject var subSheetAViewModel: SubSheetAViewModel = SubSheetAViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ZStack {
                Color.teal.opacity(0.5).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                VStack {
                    Button {
                        mainViewModel.showSubSheetA = true // Use the view model's state
                    } label: {
                        Text("Click Me")
                    }
                }
                .navigationDestination(isPresented: $mainViewModel.showSubSheetA) { // Use the view model's state
                    SubSheetA().environmentObject(subSheetAViewModel)
                }
            }
        }
        .presentationDetents([.fraction(0.25), .large], selection: $mainViewModel.selectedDetent)
        .interactiveDismissDisabled(true)
        .presentationBackgroundInteraction(.enabled)
    }
}

// MARK: View's and view model related to sub sheet A

class SubSheetAViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var showSubSheetB = false
}

struct SubSheetA: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var subSheetAViewModel: SubSheetAViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.indigo.opacity(0.5).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            VStack {
                Text("Sub sheet A")
                
                Button { subSheetAViewModel.showSubSheetB = true } label: {
                    Text("Open sub sheet B")
                }
            }
            .navigationDestination(isPresented: $subSheetAViewModel.showSubSheetB) { // Use the view model's state
                SubSheetB()
            }
        }
    }
}

// MARK: View related to sub sheet B

struct SubSheetB: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Sub view B - should stay active.")
        }
    }
}

// MARK: View's related to info view/info button on content view.

struct InfoView: View {
    @State var showInfoSubView = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            Button {
                showInfoSubView = true
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: "info.circle.fill").resizable().foregroundColor(.blue).frame(width: 30, height: 30)
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showInfoSubView) {
            InfoSubView()
        }
    }
}

struct InfoSubView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                Text("This is info sub view... tap on cancel button")
            }
            .presentationDetents([.large])
            .interactiveDismissDisabled(true)
            .presentationBackgroundInteraction(.enabled)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                    Button {
                        presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                    } label: {
                        Text("Cancel").font(.body)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Steps to produce the problem:

- Run the code above.
- Tap on "Click Me" on the bottom panel which will navigate it to subview which says  - "Sub sheet A".
- Tap on "Open sub sheet B" on this view (SubSheetA) which will open SubSheetB.
- Now don't do anything with the sheets, but tap on info button on main view to open info view.
- Once info view is opened, tap 'Cancel' on top left of this panel to close the info sheet.

Notice the bottom panel goes back to "Sub sheet A" view instead of "Sub view B - should stay active." view.

I wish to keep "Sub view B - should stay active." active in the bottom panel once info view is closed. How can I achieve this?

Note: I had asked similar question before ([SwiftUI: Maintain state of bottom sheet when another sheet is opened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77938373/swiftui-maintain-state-of-bottom-sheet-when-another-sheet-is-opened)) and the solution for it had worked for that scenario, but my stack is one more level deep now and the solution doesn't work in this case.

Would like to know how can I achieve what I want? And maybe also why solution from other post didn't work in this case?

Comment: `ContentView` is a view model already, you'll have more success if you remove the unnecessary `MainViewModel` class and any other view model classes you have.

Answer (score 0):

You may have noticed in Xcode when you run your app that it says

> Currently, only presenting a single sheet is supported.
> The next sheet will be presented when the currently presented sheet gets dismissed.

Since you passed the SubSheetAViewModel from the MainSheetView, it is being lost when the InfoSubView is presented.

You can move the SubSheetAViewModel to the top level of your app.

```swift
@main
struct MyApp: App {  // Obviously, whatever your app is called goes here
    @StateObject var subSheetAViewModel = SubSheetAViewModel()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        .environmentObject(subSheetAViewModel)
    }
}
```

Take the `@StateObject` definition out of `MainSheetView` and also remove the `.environmentObject(subSheetAViewModel)` from your call to `SubSheetA()` because it's now being inserted at a higher level.

Nothing else needs to change. Your example works for me with just that one tweak.

FYI you could also inject the view model on the `ContentView()` inside the `WindowGroup` in your main struct, or even inside of `ContentView` (where you're already defining your `MainViewModel`). As long as it's one level or more above your sheet view, it should work fine.

Comment: I know moving the view model to top level makes it work but was avoiding it since my app is complex and has many view models. If nothing works than this would be my last resort. Based on the reasoning in my earlier post - https://stackoverflow.com/a/77939536/697033, I was expecting that solution to work in this scenario as well.